# Magento 2 Customers unable to login

Tags: magento2

In my site some customers are not able to login valid credentials.

Getting error **An unspecified error occurred. Please contact us for assistance.**

Comment: issue in local or server?

Comment: Can you check `var/log/exception.log` to see any error messages?

Comment: @SHPatel issue in server

Comment: @PYYick : no didnot get any  error logs

Comment: might be need to change password if admin set change once customer login 1st time